# How to copy the record in hibernate with new primary key?

Tags: java, hibernate-4.x

I want to copy the record of a table into that same table (nothing but saving the new record with previous record values and here the primary key will auto increment) so how to do it in hibernate(is there any direct method like session.save(Obj)) and I am using Hibernate 4.1.12.

Comment: Clone and save. Or rather use a custom clone method and save the new object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making all the primary key columns null and then Session.Save(obj).

Comment: at that time it is giving exception like Hibernate: “identifier of an instance altered from A to B”

Comment: If you have this error, it means the object has not been detached from session and you update the id to null. Try detaching the object first using `evict` method

Answer (score 0):

Let us Consider:

1. Your table name as 'TestTable' with primary key 'id' (key which needs
   to be auto incremented).
2. Your Model Class is 'Test' which has a field
   'id' mapped to 'id' column of table 'TestTable'.

You can achieve what you are looking for, using the following approach:

```
Test  test  = (Test) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Test.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id", id)).uniqueResult();
test.setId(null);
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(test);
```

Comment: here also it will give exception like identifier of an instance of (class name) was altered from actual PrimaryKey to null and i think it will not work using saveOrUpdate(obj).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Test  test  = (Test) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Test.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id", id)).uniqueResult();
Test t=new Test();
t.setName(test.getName());
t.setAge(test.getAge());
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(t);
```

Or
if your table has createddate or modified date fields change that two values and save.

```
Test  test  = (Test) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Test.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id", id)).uniqueResult();
test.setCreatedDate(new Date());
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(test);
```

Comment: It works but,i thought this will be long procedure if our POJO has more properties.

Comment: Can you please give me a example on clone.I am unable to find the example.

Comment: Test t1=test.Clone(); sessionFactory.getCurrentSession.save(t1);

Comment: From where this Clone() method will come?

Comment: Test  test  = (Test) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Test.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id", id)).uniqueResult();
Test t=test.clone();
t.setName(test.getName());
t.setAge(test.getAge());
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(t);

Answer (score 0):

You can try evicting the previous object before saving the new object.

```
Test  test  = (Test) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Test.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id", id)).uniqueResult();
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().evict(test);
test.setId(1);
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(test);
```